# 1996 AIME Problem #14

Tags: contest-math, 3d

> > Problem:A $150\times 324\times 375$ rectangular solid is made by gluing together $1\times 1\times 1$ cubes. An internal diagonal of this solid passes through the interiors of how many of the $1\times 1\times 1$ cubes?

I tried it and I had no clue of approaching. Then I saw solution on AOPS but didn't find it satisfactory. The solution went like this

$150+324+375- gcd(150,324)-gcd(150,375)-gcd(324,375)+gcd(150,324,375)= 768$.

Link is
artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h46950p315374

I think they have used PIE but I don't know how it solved the problem. Anybody can explain me??

Comment: Can you provide a link to the AOPS solution you saw?

Comment: @John Omielan https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h46950p315374

Comment: Thanks. Please add that to your question text.

Comment: @MathematicalCuriosity Have you seen the 2-D version of this problem? It has the same ideas (though is much easier to approach / visualize).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this cuboid on a graph.

Now mark planes, for each dimension in the following way.

$$x=1,x=2,...,x=150$$
$$y=1,y=2,...,y=324$$
$$z=1,z=2,...,z=375$$

Now the internal diagonal passes through all such planes.

Now it is equivalent to count intersections of the diagonal with the planes, which can be easily counted with the inclusion-exclusion principle.

For clarity:
Now the part that why is it $\gcd(a,b)$: Consider starting from $(0,0,0)$. Imagine the internal diagonal as a vector. This vector has direction vector $(150,324,375)$. When you move in the direction of the positive $x$ axis, you also move $324/150$ units in the $y$ direction and similarly $375/150$ in the $z$ direction. When for example, $x$ and $y$ will be integers? Can you relate $\gcd(x,y)$ to this?

Comment: Why the no. of intersection with $x=k_1$ and $y=k_2$ is exactly $gcd(150,324)$??

Comment: There are intersectuons with only 1 integer coordinate, there are intersections with only 2 integer coorsinates and finally there are intersections with all 3 integer coordinates.

Comment: You add $150+324+375$, thats intersections with points that have only $1$ of $x,y,z$ as integer. But then points which have $2$ of $x,y,z$ as integers are overcounted so you subtract those. Then you add again the case when all $3$ of $x,y,z$ are integers.

Comment: Now the part that why is it $\gcd(a,b)$: Consider starting from $(0,0,0)$. Imagine the internal diagonal as a vector. This vector has direction vector $(150,324,375)$. When you move in the direction of the positive $x$ axis, you also move $324/150$ units in the $y$ direction and similarly $375/150$ in the $z$ direction. When for example, $x$ and $y$ will be integers? Can you relate $\gcd(x,y)$ to this?

Comment: @h- squared Thanks